# how to random create objects from specific 5 points?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Halo, I am developing a mini flash game.

Gameplay:
Player control character and move left and right to collect money coin.
There are 5 points that money and bomb release and move from top to bottom. When character collide with money then increase money else hit bomb age increase by 1. Once the age is 99, the game is over and the money is the final scores

Here is my code:

```
package Class
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Game extends MovieClip
{
    private var bgi:BGI;
    private var character:Character;
    private var money:Money;
    private var bomb:Bomb;
    private var moneysource : MoneySource;
    private var moneytext:TextField;
    private var agetext:TextField;
    private var characterspeed:int;
    private var objectspeed:int;
    private var age:int;
    private var moneyscore:int;
    private var moneyinscreen:int;
    private var moneyVector:Vector.<MovieClip >  = new Vector.<MovieClip >;
    private var noofmoney:int;
    private var noofbomb:int;
    private var bombVector:Vector.<MovieClip >  = new Vector.<MovieClip >;

    public function Game()
    {
        bgi = null;
        character = null;
        money = null;
        bomb = null;
        moneysource = null;
        Initialize();
    }

    private function Initialize()
    {

        age = 0;
        moneyscore = 0;
        noofmoney = 15;
        noofbomb = 10;

        bgi = new BGI  ;
        bgi.x = 0;
        bgi.y = 0;

        character = new Character  ;
        character.x = 335;
        character.y = 400;

        bomb = new Bomb  ;
        bomb.x = 40;
        bomb.y = 0;



        moneytext = new TextField  ;
        moneytext.x = 450;
        moneytext.y = 0;
        moneytext.defaultTextFormat = Config.TxtFormat;
        moneytext.text = "Money : 0";
        moneytext.width = 200;

        agetext = new TextField  ;
        agetext.x = 700;
        agetext.y = 0;
        agetext.defaultTextFormat = Config.TxtFormat;
        agetext.text = "Age : 0";
        agetext.width = 100;

        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(bgi);
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(character);
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(agetext);
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneytext);

        moneysource = new MoneySource;
        moneysource.x = 61;
        moneysource.y = 50;
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneysource);

        moneysource = new MoneySource;
        moneysource.x = 211;
        moneysource.y = 50;
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneysource);

        moneysource = new MoneySource;
        moneysource.x = 371;
        moneysource.y = 50;
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneysource);

        moneysource = new MoneySource;
        moneysource.x = 531;
        moneysource.y = 50;
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneysource);

        moneysource = new MoneySource;
        moneysource.x = 691;
        moneysource.y = 50;
        Config.CurrentStage.addChild(moneysource);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < noofmoney; i++)
        {
            money = new Money  ;
            money.vel = RandomRange(6,7);
            money.x = RandomRange(0,750);
            money.y = RandomRange(0,100);
            Config.CurrentStage.addChild(money);
            moneyVector.push(money);
        }

        for (var j:int = 0; j < noofbomb; j++)
        {
            bomb = new Bomb  ;
            bomb.vel = RandomRange(6,7);
            bomb.x = RandomRange(0,750);
            bomb.y = RandomRange(0,100);
            Config.CurrentStage.addChild(bomb);
            bombVector.push(bomb);
        }*/

        Config.CurrentStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        Config.CurrentStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,Control);
    }

    private function Update(evt:Event)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < moneyVector.length; i++)
        {
            if (moneyVector[i].hitTestObject(character))
            {
                Config.CurrentStage.removeChild(moneyVector[i]);
                moneyVector.splice(i, 1);
                moneyscore +=  400;
                moneytext.text = "Money : " + moneyscore.toString();
                money = new Money  ;
                //money.vel = RandomRange(6,7);
                money.x = RandomRange(0,750);
                money.y = RandomRange(0,100);
                Config.CurrentStage.addChild(money);
                moneyVector.push(money);

            }
            if (moneyVector[i].y > Config.ScreenHeight)
            {
                moneyVector[i].x = RandomRange(0,750);
                moneyVector[i].y =  -  moneyVector[i].height;
            }
        }

        for (var j:int = 0; j < bombVector.length; j++)
        {
            if (bombVector[j].hitTestObject(character))
            {

                Config.CurrentStage.removeChild(bombVector[j]);
                bombVector.splice(j, 1);
                age++;
                agetext.text = "Age : " + age.toString();
                bomb = new Bomb  ;
                bomb.vel = RandomRange(6,7);
                bomb.x = RandomRange(0,750);
                bomb.y = RandomRange(0,100);
                Config.CurrentStage.addChild(bomb);
                bombVector.push(money);

            }
            if (bombVector[j].y > Config.ScreenHeight)
            {
                bombVector[j].x = RandomRange(0,750);
                bombVector[j].y =  -  bombVector[j].height;
            }
        }
    }

    private function Control(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        characterspeed = 15;
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            character.x -=  characterspeed;
            if (character.x <= 0)
            {
                character.x = 0;
            }
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            character.x +=  characterspeed;
            if (character.x >= 670)
            {
                character.x = 670;
            }
        }
    }

    private function RandomRange(min:Number,max:Number):Number
    {
        return Math.random() * max - min + min;
    }

}

}
```

This is my Game:
Currently, the bomb and money random appear X, 100 with 15 money and 10 bombs in a screen.
What I want is, how to amend it become money and bomb appear from specific point, after that the money and bomb when hit the wall will bounce back.
Anyone can provide me some code? Thanks

An example similar game play with my game is 
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzQ8PP5-TVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy path to getting a realistic simulation of the money and bombs falling could be achieved using Box2d.

Here is a link to a demo with complete source code in which balls are randomly added above a row of pegs. This is the same style of play as video you linked to.

http://wonderfl.net/c/aeyl

In that example, you could replace the code that spawns the ball with a function that chooses a random starting place. Here is one way to write such a function:

```
function chooseSpawnPoint():Point{
   var points:Array = new Array();
   points[0] = new Point(0,50);
   points[1] = new Point(0,100);
   points[2] = new Point(0,150);
   points[3] = new Point(0,200);
   points[4] = new Point(0,250);
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length);
}
```

*you could improve performance of that function by initializing the "points" array outside of the function call. If you did that it might appear something like this:

```
var points:Array = new Array();
points[0] = new Point(0,50);
points[1] = new Point(0,100);
points[2] = new Point(0,150);
points[3] = new Point(0,200);
points[4] = new Point(0,250);
// Add as many points as you want. 
// the function will choose one at random based on 
// the number of points you add to the points array.

function chooseSpawnPoint():Point{
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, mind to give me your contact? (msn / skype) i need pro to guide me on flash.

Comment: Thanks, but the best place to find actionscript pros is here on Stackoverflow. There is strength in numbers.Post your questions here that others with the same problems may find them.

Comment: how about the part that render object?
first 90 seconds, i needs to render 10 money objects and 0 bombs
after that, i need to render 15 money objects and 8 bombs
once collided, the particular object will disappear and the spawn point spawn new one.
i did tried, it can render it out and respawn but when hittest, the game like jam and stuck 
i think is the removechild() and addchild() there got problem

Comment: an error occur at the return random there
 
   Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type flash.geom:Point.